# Inconsistant dates appearing for IPad .jpg files on a PC

Tags: ipad, date

I wrote a Windows NetBeans program to rename files to "file creation date/time", i.e. `150912_140023.JPG`, to merge photos chronologically from a camera, Droid and iPad.  I encountered a problem with the iPad .jpg files.

I am seeing an inconsistency in the file dates. If I do a DOS `dir` command on an iPad photo, I see a file date of `09/12/15`.  This is the date my program is retrieving. However, in a windows directory window, I see a date of `09/07/15` for the same file.

The correct date of the file is `09/07/15`.

Why is there a difference?  Can I replicate the date determination performed by a directory window to get the correct date?

Answer (score 0):

[The iOS filesystem stores four timestamps for a file](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man2/stat.2.html): last access time, last data modification time, last status change time (time that the inode was changed), and creation time.

[NTFS stores three timestamps for a file](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724290(v=vs.85).aspx): last access time, last write time, and creation time.

Copying a file from an iPad to Windows might update any of these times on the copy, depending on how the copy program was written.

The `DIR` command displays the last write timestamp by default (I believe). You can specify which timestamp you want it to display using a command-line flag. The `/t:c` flag requests creation time. The `/t:a` flag requests last access time. The `/t:w` flag requests last write time.

It sounds like you want to run `DIR /t:c`.